# How to display name of user who is already logged in?

Tags: jquery, ajax

When registered, user is required to fill full name, email, and password. But when login user only needs to input email and password. I want to greet user but only "undefined" shown on the webpage.

[image]
[image]

I still cannot add key of full name to LocalStorage, I dont know how or whats wrong with my codes:

```
function authentication() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
        $("#login-page").hide()
        $("#register-page").hide()
        $("#add-todo-page").hide()
        $('#welcome-name').text(localStorage.full_name);
        // $("#navbar").show()
        $("#home-page").show()
        // $("#todo-list").show()
        homePage()
    } else {
        loginPage()
        // console.log("gak ada akses token")
    }
}
```

```
function login() {
    // console.log("masuk login")
    let email = $("#login-email").val()
    let password = $("#login-password").val()
    $.ajax({
        url: `${baseUrl}/users/login`,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            email,
            password
        }
    })
        .done((response) => {
            // console.log("masuk res login")
            localStorage.setItem("access_token", response.access_token)
            localStorage.setItem("full_name", response.full_name)
            authentication()

        })
        .fail((xhr, text) => {
            swal("Try again!", xhr.responseJSON.error, "error")
            console.log(xhr.responseJSON.error)
        })
        .always(_ => {
            $("#login-form").trigger("reset")
        })
}
```

is it possible to show user's full name even though user doesn't log in with user name (only with email and password)?

Comment: you might have set `undefined` to localStorage.

Comment: try `console.log` response in `.done((response) => { ... }` to see if you get `undefined` or not.

Comment: @Layhout yes i got undefined for the response.full_name

Answer (score 1):

change localStorage.full_name to localStorage.getItem('full_name')

Comment: `localStorage.full_name` is a shorthanded for `localStorage.getItem('full_name')`

Comment: yeah. In this case, he might set `undefine` to `full_name`.
I think we just need to store `access_token`, whenver render `home page` call api with access_token to get user info then save in global variable

Comment: @Hao.Le what keyword should i use to google further info about this?

Comment: @Flo maybe this will help 
[Link](https://dev.to/tienbku/authentication-authorization-with-react-js-example-18e)
don't care about react logic. focus on the flow chart at `User Registration and User Login Flow`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).